# Using an If statement to determine if a method has been called

Tags: c#

I need to figure out a way of using an if statement to determine whether a method in my code has been called, in order to perform an action. Is this possible in C#?

Comment: More details, please. Any reason you can't set a property in the class when the method is called, and check that? Or better, use an event?

Comment: You need to give more information: Does the method do something you can check (change some state in an object?).  If not, are you able to modify the method so it can cooperate with your test?  Do you need to know if the method has been called at all or if it's been called on a particular object (assuming it's not a static method).

Comment: Can you give more detail about what you are trying to do?  Give the steps in simple terms.  Meaning Fun1 is called, once fun1 has been called then fun2 is executed.  Without the detail you will have a very hard time getting the help you need since this is a very vague question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem?

```
class MyClass {
  private bool m_myFunctionCalled = false;

  public void myFunction() {
    m_myFunctionCalled = true;
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the edit.  I was just trying to figure out how to edit the code (just figured it out) when I saw someone already had.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
public class MyClass
{
     private bool myFuncWasCalled = false;

     public void MyFunc()
     {
          myFuncWasCalled=true;      
     }

     public bool WasMyFuncCalled()
     {
        return myFuncWasCalled;
     }
     public void anotherFunc()
     {
          if(myFuncWasCalled)
          {
            // do some action
          }               
     }
}
```

See how to use it in this [linqpad](/questions/tagged/linqpad)-programm

[image: LINQPad]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just make the method return something at the end.

For example:

```csharp
...
bool temp = MyFunction();
if (temp == true) {
   // true was returned
}
...

bool MyFunction() {
   return true;
}
```